# Is this good to use file-based PHP cache on news/article based websites?

Tags: php, caching, pear

Is this a good idea to use file caching on article/news style php websites with 10-15k records to solve PHP performance problems?

Is it better to use something like "cache_lite" than fetching an article or news from database by a "SELECT" query?

What about members profile pages? (~200k)

Comment: Why not test it and find out? No one knows what your server setup is like, so maybe mysql queries are incredibly slow, but you're running off an incredibly fast disk drive. Or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you should defiantly use cache. It helps speed things up when you have many/large queries to execute.

You can even cache part of the article or whatever you want. You can cache whole pages if you wanted.

Check out memcache'ing http://php.net/memcache

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I personally do this with content that usually is static (which profile pages are - only refreshing the cached page when the info is updated), and i've seen a decrease in loadspeed by up to 200 times by using a custom tailored caching system, so it is a very good idea

Answer (score 0):

yes. It will be good.

I will suggest you to go with memory cache in place of file cache. 
Use Memcache